# How to fetch a Value from List using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a response as below

Result:

`[version[attributes={}; value=[3.0.2-open-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.0.10-ALIYUN-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.0.11-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.2.0-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.2.4-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.6.1-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.6.2-SNAPSHOT]], version[attributes={}; value=[3.6.2-ForEagleEye-SNAPSHOT]]]`

Now how can I fetch the value of version. I want it to be displayed as

> [3.0.2-open-SNAPSHOT,3.0.10-ALIYUN-SNAPSHOT,
>   3.2.0-SNAPSHOT,3.2.4-SNAPSHOT,3.2.4-SNAPSHOT,3.6.2-ForEagleEye-SNAPSHOT]]

How can I fetch it using groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return version[0].value()// **will return the value**
```